# Zend-Framework2. Sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework2

I need some help, I have to implement this sql query in zend2:

```
SET @i:=-1; SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, AVG(ch01) AS ch01avg  FROM (
     SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS rownum,FLOOR(@i/60) AS GGG,ch01 
     FROM binTable 
     WHERE SUBDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 11 DAY)<= start_date_time
)AS t GROUP BY GGG;
```

Feel free to use any other sql query as long it fulfulls the purpose, which is: getting the average of ch01 of every 60 entries.

Im not a native english speaker, Im eastern european :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there i maneged to find a solution which works for me:

Having an instance of

> Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway

object which represents the table from which i want to make the query I did this:

> $this->binTable is the Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway object:

```
$result = $this->binTable->getAdapter()->query(" HERE GOES THE SQL QUERY ")->execute();

     use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;

$resultSet = new ResultSet;
$resultSet->initialize($result);
```